# Inserting an HTML comment in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

Is it possible to insert an HTML comment (you know, the kind that is wrapped in `<!-- -->`) in shiny? `shiny::tags` seems to support various HTML tags, but not comments.

The use case would be if you want to put some audit log data about your app in the HTML output as a comment, so they are not shown to the user but can be seen in *View Source* mode.

Comment: maybe use `tags$meta(comment = "my comment text here")` instead of a comment?

Comment: `HTML("<!-- the comment -->")` ?

Comment: Stephane, if you post that comment as an answer, I will mark it as such and close this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `HTML` function:

```
HTML("<!-- the comment -->")
```

You can split:

```
HTML(
  "<!-- ",
  "this ",
  "is ",
  "a comment ",
  "-->"
)
```